# Is it possible to get a transparent cuboid that's opaque in bulk but does not have any faces?

Tags: graphics3d, opacity

I am having some trouble getting ListContourPlot3D to behave correctly towards making a density-like plot for three-dimensional data, so I thought I would build an alternative myself by stacking together a bunch of semi-transparent cuboids.

To some extent, this worked OK, but I don't really like the look of it:

> [image]

A lot of what I don't like is the discretized structure coming from the faces of the cuboids. What I would like is for Mathematica to produce a translucent cube of jelly whose colour and opacity I can control, with the opacity coming from a bulk calculation rather than from the faces.

So, I thought I would try just removing the faces,

```
Graphics3D[{
  EdgeForm[None],
  FaceForm[None],
  Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}]
  }
 , Boxed -> False
 ]
```

but that didn't work like I expected:

> [image]

(i.e. the whole thing just vanished.)

Is what I want possible within Mathematica? If so, how can I achieve it?

Huge thanks in advance!

Comment: Alternatively to my answer, you might be able to work directly with [`ListDensityPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListDensityPlot3D.html)

Comment: If your data is such that you can attach a value to each point on a cubic lattice (i.e., v[[i,j,k]]) then Image3D may be helpful—there are some good examples in the documentation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe something using [`Raster3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Raster3D.html) with the option `Method -> {"InterpolateValues" -> True}` can work for you?

```
Graphics3D@Raster3D[
  {{{1}}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}, 
  ColorFunction -> (Opacity[0.01, Red] &), 
  Method -> {"InterpolateValues" -> True}
  ]
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe you want `ColorFunction -> (Opacity[0.01 #, Red] &)`, so that the color depends on the "density" value in the raster. (+1)

Answer (score 4):

Something like:

```
Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.2], EdgeForm[None], FaceForm[Yellow], 
  Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}]}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't really work for me. If I add a second cuboid, `Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.2], EdgeForm[None], FaceForm[Yellow], Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}], Cuboid[{1, 0, 0}]}, Boxed -> False]`, I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9UpT.png), and the visibility of the middle wall kills its applicability for the plot I want to build.